# How to use DB connections in Actix several times per function?

Tags: database, rust, actix-web, r2d2

At https://actix.rs/docs/databases/ there is an example:

```rust
async fn index(pool: web::Data<DbPool>, name: web::Path<(String)>) -> impl Responder {
    let name = name.into_inner();

    let conn = pool.get().expect("couldn't get db connection from pool");

    let user = web::block(move || actions::insert_new_user(&conn, &user))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        })?;
    
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(user))
}
```

What to do if I need several SQL queries in one function? The following obviously won't work due to moving `conn`:

```rust
async fn index(pool: web::Data<DbPool>, name: web::Path<(String)>) -> impl Responder {
    let name = name.into_inner();

    let conn = pool.get().expect("couldn't get db connection from pool");

    let user1 = web::block(move || actions::insert_new_user(&conn, &user))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        })?;

    // ... asynchronous code here

    let user2 = web::block(move || actions::insert_new_user(&conn, &user))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        })?;
    
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(user))
}
```

I can receive several connections by repeated calls of `pool.get()`, but that inefficient to open a new SQL connection when one connection is enough.

So, how to deal with this?

Comment: Simply remove `move`? Why then in the official example it uses `move`?

Comment: Removal of `move` leads to `NonNull<pq_sys::pg_conn> cannot be shared between threads safely
within PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>, the trait Sync is not implemented for NonNull<pq_sys::pg_conn>`. So, it seems the only solution is to obtain a new connection every time :-(

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move **the reference**, not the connection itself:

```rust
async fn index(pool: web::Data<DbPool>, name: web::Path<(String)>) -> impl Responder {
    let name = name.into_inner();

    let conn_ = pool.get().expect("couldn't get db connection from pool");
    let conn = &conn_;
    let user1 = web::block(move || actions::insert_new_user(&conn, &user))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        })?;

    // ... asynchronous code here

    let user2 = web::block(move || actions::insert_new_user(&conn, &user))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        })?;
    
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(user))
}
```

Your problem can be reduced to (not working version):

```rust
struct Conn {}

fn foo(_: &Conn) {}


fn main() {

    let conn_ = Conn {};
    
    (move || foo(&conn_))();
    (move || foo(&conn_))();
    
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4501ff78934c4a17c52df7a202c43f6b)

Working version:

```rust
struct Conn {}

fn foo(_: &Conn) {}


fn main() {

    let conn_ = Conn {};
    let conn = &conn_;
    (move || foo(conn))();
    (move || foo(conn))();
    
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccaae39654fe5d872c364332c4047239)

Comment: See my answer with explanation that your answer is wrong (please don't delete, just comment).

Comment: Following your solution, I nevertheless get an error. See my new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70825457/856090